# input background transpeent jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

how can i set background color transparent in jquery mobile. I try this code but it is not work.

```
td input{
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
    }
```

Comment: `div.ui-input-text, div.ui-input-search { styles here }`

Comment: No that is not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vnvxu5j3/

Comment: Your jsfiddle code result same as a result of code i mention above. i have a background picture and i want to see it in input.